# Multiple Application Instances with Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

How would I go about creating an Codeigniter application that resides on multiple servers and has a hook that sends users to different instances based on the load balance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't user PHP for that. Routing users between servers it's a job for Apache.

Take a look at this http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html

Your domain acts as a proxy for your many web servers. Apache balance the requests for each server.

I've never really used it, but I guess that's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't use a CI hook per-say I would use ngnix or apahce2 as your load balancer / gateway to your app. And if you are worried about load first ensure you are using Memcached (or similar) to try and take the load off your main DataSource and if applicable use a CDN for your images/js.

Answer (score 0):

I would put System on you best server, then make multicopy of application and rename them with a increased unique number, like app1, app2 ... then on index.php I will define a variable that checks memory or cpu of server, then compare like:

if $cpu > 80 || $memory > 900 
   $application = "app2";

assuming that you have 1024 mb ram. Also you can do even more by adding sessions and filling vars per session and making a switch() for more instances.

here is a good example of doing on apache http://www.ctrip.ufl.edu/apache2-cluster-in-debian-lenny-howto